# Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\Factory] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, broadcasting

I kept getting

```
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\Factory] is not instantiable.
```

As soon as I added

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

into my app.php, can someone please help ?

## Updated

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',

    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider::class,
    HTMLMin\HTMLMin\HTMLMinServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,


],
```

---

**app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have `Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider` in your `config/app.php` `providers` array?

Comment: yes it's way in the bottom.

Comment: Can you show the code inside the `BroadcastServiceProvider`?

Comment: no it is not, `Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider`  im guessing there was an upgrade at some point ... you need to add this exact provider to that array ... in a fresh 5.7 install it would be the second provider in the list

Comment: @lagbox : What you mean ? I don't get you.

Comment: @ChinLeung : I added more codes for you.

Comment: **Disclaimer :** I updated my Laravel project from 5.1 to 5.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider` in your `providers` list.

This is part of the upgrade guide for 5.1 I believe.